# Как пишется "на()счет"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Как пишется "на()счет" в значении "по поводу": слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлог *насчёт* пишется слитно: *договориться насчёт выходного.*

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае слитно.
Положить на счет в банке/ прийти в банк насчет кредита.

Answer (score 1):

Это производный предлог, поэтому пишется слитно.

Answer (score -1):

Слитно, слитно, слитно и ещё раз слитно!